# Linux bash script - for loop one-liner sleep with timeout and multiple variables - syntax problem

Tags: bash, for-loop, sleep

I want to make a wait syntax in my shell script until something else is done.

I would like to make it as flexible as possible so that if I need it again for something else I just have to change the numbers.

What I've got so far is:

```bash
    #! /bin/bash
    for i in $(seq 1 20); do sleep 0.2; [ $i = 19 ] && echo "19" || echo $i; done
```

My target result should look something like this:

```bash
    for i=0 iStart=1 iEnd=20 iGoal=19 iDuration=2 in $(seq $iStart $iEnd); do sleep $(echo "scale=3; $iDuration / $iEnd" | bc ); [ $i = $iGoal ] && echo "${iGoal} !!!" || echo $i; done
```

*Problems* I have / description:

- *I don't know how to define multiple variables in the for loop*:
- $i = counter
- $iStart = range start for seq
- $iEnd = range end for seq
- $iGoal = target number for if condition
- $iDuration = total time in seconds until timeout reached (exit 1 or whatever) where I take the avg value per pass:
- *I don't know much about rounding numbers in bash scripts, so I'm not sure how I can achieve a solution that is as bash-compatible as possible*
- It would be great if the result would work for as many bash variants as possible.

Maybe I also could put the calculation inside the initial definitions for a little performance gain but I do not care much atm.

The final result:

```bash
echo $(date +"%T.%N"); iStart=1; iEnd=20; iGoal=19; iDuration=2; iSleep=$(bc <<<"scale = 3; ${iDuration} / ( ${iEnd} - ${iStart} + 1 )"); for i in $(seq "$iStart" "$iEnd"); do sleep "$iSleep"; if [ "$i" -eq "$iGoal" ]; then echo "${iGoal} goal"; else echo "$i"; fi; done; echo $(date +"%T.%N")
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner?

Comment: My syntax was short in the beginning and I like writing one-liners; I didn't get it right; I want to learn.

Comment: Put it in a function, then calling the function is a one-liner

Comment: Get your code working first, then cram it all onto one line if you feel that's useful for some reason. Asking for a one-liner tells us you care more about brevity than you do about robustness, efficiency, clarity, portability, or anything else that distinguishes good from bad software and so YMMV with getting a good answer.

Comment: Regarding "I want to make a wait syntax in my shell script until something else is done." - look at the man page for [wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wait.1p.html) as that's what it does.

Comment: @EdMorton Huh? I don't get it. I use one-liner for scripts/code where I know I don't need to care much because it's working good. It makes the code more readable, like a function. Do you think this is a bad approach?

Comment: Yes because cramming your code onto 1 line makes it harder to read (definitely not more readable!), harder to spot bugs, harder to enhance, and can lead to poor choices that favor brief solutions over ones that are better in the ways that matter.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify, in particular the use of both `sh` and `bash` is kind-of contradicting. Take that chance to remove the `linux` tag as well, see its description for context. That said, your hashbang line is wrong plus it only works when the file is executable and when it is not passed as argument to a different interpreter.

Comment: Note that sh and bash are two different shells. If you won't accept answers that use bash-only syntax, remove the bash tag and keep only the sh tag. If you will, remove the sh tag and keep only the bash tag.

Comment: Also, note that `sleep 0.2` is itself a GNUism. If you want to be compatible with systems that only implement the baseline POSIX standard, only integers are guaranteed to be accepted here.

Comment: Also, note that poll-based waiting is suboptimal (increases both overhead and latency). Much better to use advisory locking (`flock`, `lockfile`, etc) whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put variable assignments at the beginning of a command.

```
iStart=1 iEnd=20 iGoal=19 iDuration=2 iSleep=$(bc <<<"scale = 3; "$iDuration" / ("$iEnd" - "$iStart" - 1)") for i in $(seq "$iStart" "$iEnd"); do sleep "$iSleep"; [ "$i" = "$iGoal" ] && echo "$iGoal" || echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: The only reason I see to downvote this was a missing close `)` for the `$(bc...)`. Agree with advice to O.P. in comments above, this should be in a function. Good luck to all.

Comment: @7three you asked how to do something and Barmar showed you how to do that thing. Downvoting it because it's not crammed onto 1 line reinforces [my earlier point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202872/linux-bash-script-for-loop-one-liner-sleep-with-timeout-and-multiple-variables?noredirect=1#comment136102417_77202872) about why people are reluctant to answer questions that ask for one-liners.

Comment: @7three I originally wrote it as one line but it was hard to read. If you want to replace all the newlines with `;` in your code, feel free. The logic is the same, formatting is irrelevant.

Comment: Almost any shell script can be turned into a one-liner if you don't care how long the line is.

Comment: Re sanity of one liners : Speaking from personal experience (a long time ago), newer programmers (or those people that ***are really sure of themselves*** (-; ) like to test/push technologies to the limit and see what happens. As long as your boss doesn't mind supporting this experimentation, I guess it's OK. Just IMHO.

Comment: @shellter 
Regarding one-liners: It might not be easy for someone else to read. But I find it extremely practical if you write a script for yourself and then look for something. Then it's just one line to read through and you know: Aha, that's ok. Functions always need the function itself and then the call itself. I don't do a business with it, so it doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: @7three I give in, I've reformatted it as a one-liner.

Comment: @Barmar Nice. What's about my answer regarding the if else part? Is something wrong with it? Because I could delete my answer and accept yours as solution?

Comment: It looks fine to me. I simply copied that part from your original code, it didn't seem relevant to the point of the question.